# Setting Z offset on Artillery Hornet (Marlin 2.0.7.2)

Tags: marlin, z-axis, print-axis-offset

After leveling the corners of the bed and doing a manual mesh bed leveling (both options on the menu LCD) I adjust the babystep Z while printing to get a perfect first layer.

Ideally, I would take note of the optimal babystep Z value and store it as Z offset, but there´s no Z offset option in the LCD menu. The only similar setting I can find is (only while printing) **Tune** > **Bed Z** but this setting doesn´t affect anything. If I adjust babystep Z I can clearly see changes in Z height but not with Bed Z.

Does anyone have any idea how to store the babystep Z value? (I´ve already tried adjusting the babystep Z and then selecting the **Store Settings** option but that doesn´t work) Or maybe how to store my Z offset value through Pronterface?

PS: I recently started 3D printing, I know how to send commands through the Pronterface terminal, but haven´t learned how to modify firmware yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the Hornet, which is in **Motion** (so not when printing, just when idle), then **Bed Z**. I have never used it since I just level manually but if you want to configure it via firmware then you can do it there.

If you want to offset each of the 9 points individually you can also do it on the same menu, select **Level Bed** instead and it will take you routinely through each point so you can introduce individual Z values.

If you want to do it via command you can use [M851](https://www.3dprintbeast.com/set-x-y-z-offsets-with-m851-g-code/). I'm citing the relevant part from the guide:

> 1. **Start by resetting the Z offset**. You can do this with the command
>    **M851 Z0**, which will ensure that there is no pre-existing offset to
>    throw our calculations off.
> 2. **Home the printer**. Use the **G28** G-code to trigger auto-homing, which will bring all the axes to the 0 point.
> 3. **Disable hardware endstops**. You can use the **M121** G-code to do so.
> 4. **Disable software endstops**. Use the **M211** G-code with the **S0** parameter
>    to do so. Place a piece of paper on the bed in line with the nozzle.
>    We will be using this piece of paper to know when to stop moving the
>    nozzle in the next step.
> 5. **Bring the nozzle down slowly until it touches the piece of paper**.
>    You can do this via either the built-in panel or the software of
>    your choice.
> 6. **Write the Z-axis value down and run the M851 G-code with it**. For
>    instance, if your Z-axis shows -2.5, run **M851 Z-2.5**.
>
> [...]
>
> Finally, use the G-codes **M120** and **M211 S1** to enable the hardware and
> software endstops, and run the **M500** command to save your settings to
> the EEPROM, which will allow your 3D printer to load them back
> automatically every time you boot it.

My personal way of keeping the Hornet bed leveled is manually instead of by firmware by having 5 individual files that each have a square at a different position (all the corners + center though I rarely use the latter) and when I notice prints start to look ugly on a certain corner I know I have to use that square to level.

The rule is: **if you see spaces between each line, raise the bed. If you see roughness, lower the bed**. You don't need to print the whole square either, just enough for you to see the filament fuses correctly as every line is being laid.

[image: Levelling guide]

(I understand this last point doesn't answer your question per se but I wanted to give you every option available to accomplish your levelling including manual)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and adjust it in Marlin itself but it will be a long, frustrating process of trial and error. Alternatively,  if you are using Cura you can download a plug-in that allows you to adjust z-offset. You just have to remember to reslice your model if you print on multiple surfaces with different thickness